# Non-Database Generated Primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up a table like this:

```
Account
-ID (PK, int, not null)
-AccountID (PK, int, not null)
-... other scalars
```

Now, I want the ID property to be generated by the database as usual. However, I want the other part of the composite key, AccountID, to come from an API that we consume. However, on object creation:

```
using(var context = new FGContext){
     Account a = context.Accounts.Create();
     context.Accounts.Attach(a);
     a.AccountID = GetAccountIDFromAPI();
     ....

     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get the error "The property 'AccountID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified." - Which makes sense to me. I can drop AccountID as part of the primary key, however we query by it all the time and I'd like to keep it that way for performance reasons.

Is there any way around this? I've already tried DatabaseGeneratedOption.None, which didn't work (I'm assuming because the field is also marked as Key).

Comment: How about adding a Unique constraint and an index to AccountID? You could even put a Clustered index on AccountID if you don't really need it on ID.

Comment: This is probably the only option, as further research shows it is not possible within Entity Framework. Just seems odd to me since this is probably a relatively common use case (indeed the only use case I can think of for generating your own primary keys).